# Как найти пакеты в зависимостях у которых есть пакета X?

Tags: debian

Требуется найти все пакеты имеющие в зависимостях пакет X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-cache rdepends название_пакета
```

Comment: если `rdepends` отсутствует, устанавливается так `$ sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends`

Comment: @tCode, это, наверно, если сборка очень старая. на сервере двухгодичной давности только что проверил, сработало без проблем :)

Comment: это я так для информации)

Comment: @tCode, потому и помечен, как полезный :)

Comment: В качестве пользовательского интерфейса можно wajig использовать, который в одной команде несколько инструментов собирает по работе с пакетами.